# Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename on WSL2 Ubuntu running on windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, meteor, open-source, wsl-2

I am trying to set up the meteorjs development environment and am trying to run the command './meteor --help' to install the dependencies. I am trying to install it in a local folder on my desktop thorugh WSL2. But whenever I run the command I get this error.

I have tried running

```
sudo ./meteor --help
```

But the command line advises against running it and does not run it.

I have also tried running

```
sudo chown -R $USER .
sudo chmod -R 755 .
```

in the directory where I want to install meteor but after running the ./meteor command I get the same error. The Ubuntu WSL2 is running as adminstrator as well.